# When exactly is the space allocated in memory for a constant in Java at compile-time or runtime?

Tags: java, constants, runtime, final, compile-time

I'm learning about Java constants and I want to know when exactly is the space allocated in memory for a constant. Is it at compile time or runtime? For ex I have a constant like this:

```
public static final int NUMBER = 5;
```

I know that for an instance or class variable the space is allocated in memory at runtime, for an instance variable the space is allocated in memory when an object is created, and for a class variable the moment is when the class is loaded. But what's happening for a constant? I know the compiler do some optimization when it finds this constant and replaces every the constant name everywhere in the code with its value. But when exactly is the space allocated in memory for this constant NUMBER? At compile time or runtime?

Comment: @Turing85 Java is chock full of constants, such as the one in the question. String literals are another example. There is a constant pool in the class file format.

Comment: @user207421 Huh. dug a little in the JLS. You're right, there are constant variables...

Comment: The answer to the question is ‘both’. The compiler allocates space in stack frames and the constant pool in terms of sizes, and the JVM allocates memory to correspond to those sizes.

Comment: "and for a class variable the moment is when the class is loaded" You just answered your own question. You even identified that the compiler can inline the constants. What more do you want to be answered?

Comment: @Sweeper as I said "for a class variable the moment is when the class is loaded", but I want to be sure about the moment when the memory is allocated for a constant like NUMBER (or compile time constant) because I asked Chatgpt and it say "memory for compile-time constants in Java is allocated during the compilation process and is part of the bytecode in the class file. "

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocation could never happen at compile-time, since compiling produces only the byte-code and never ever allocates any memory for run-time. Memory allocation at compile-time would result in a memory leak. You would never know when to release the memory (halting-problem / will I ever use this again?). Maybe what you mean: while compiling, the compiler substitutes (as you state) your identifier with the literal / value of the "constant".